# How to attach the unity menu applet to the gnome panel ?

Tags: unity, gnome, 11.10, launcher, 3d

Can someone please tell how to attach the Unity Menu Applet back to the Gnome Panel?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure i understand correctly but... you can't.
There is no gnome panel. It's all unity. In 11.10 the menu button is on the launcher by design. There's no "app for that" to change it. :)

Comment: Yes, but in 11.04, the Menu Applet was on the top panel by default, is there anyway to re-enable that design?

Comment: @Eric, that was unity 3.x. Unity 4.x (ubuntu 11.10) uses the launcher for launching the menu. There is no option to change that. Canonical decided so because many users failed to notice the button and got lost.

Answer (score 0):

There is certainly a way to get rid of the Unity menu.

sudo aptitude install gnome-panel - followed by a log out/log in where you select the Gnome panel as your desktop should do the job for you. I heartily recommend it.

Comment: I don't think that is what he wants. Using gnome 2 is a totally different thing.